# Infinity symbol with HTML

Tags: html, html-entities, infinity

How can I display an infinity symbol (like the one in the picture) using HTML?

[image: infinity symbol]

Answer (score 347, accepted):

Use the HTML entity `&infin;` or `&#8734;`.

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales Well... [googling for `utf-8 infinity symbol`](https://www.google.pl/#q=utf-8+infinity+symbol&safe=active) gives me many interesting results within 3 seconds, including [utf8icons.com](http://www.utf8icons.com/character/8734/infinity), [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221e/index.htm) and others.

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales also [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org) site is very good and increasing in data available.

Answer (score 114):

You can use the following:

- literal: `∞` (if the encoding you use can encode it — UTF-8 can, for example)
- character reference: `&#8734;` (decimal), `&#x221E;` (hexadecimal)
- entity reference: `&infin;`

But whether it is displayed correctly does also depend on the font the text is displayed with.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the font-dependence. This is often overlooked in case of "unicode characters".

Answer (score 27):

∞

This does *not* require a HTML entity if you are using a modern encoding (such as UTF-8).  And if you're not already, you probably should be.

Comment: Curious: since I don't have a ∞ on my keyboard, would I always have to copy/paste the previous ∞? How do you get it there the first time? I find it easier and faster to type `&infin;`, but if there's a faster way to get this on to the screen with just a plain ol' keyboard, please share

Comment: The “Typing Special Characters” section here might help: http://www.xvsxp.com/misc/keyboard.php

Comment: I'm aware of the character maps, but I'm a fast typist and having to toggle to a UI and then back to the editor slows me down. I can still type `&infin;` faster.

Comment: I don't think there's a default key for infinity.  However, like anything else you can set up a key shortcut.  Jonas Kölker recommended Compose+1/0  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311244/keyboard-layout-for-international-programmers/662389#662389)

Comment: What's your environment?  On the Mac, it's option-5.  In GTK+, it's C-S-u 2 2 1 E.  On Windows, it's ALT 2 3 6 (keypad).  A good text editor will also have a way to define an abbrev for it.

Answer (score 10):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references):

```
&infin;
```

Answer (score 10):

According to [List of XML and HTML character entity references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references):

```
&#8734;
```

[The Google search using your original question gets several useful results: 
**How can I display an infinity symbol using HTML**](http://www.google.com/search?q=How+can+I+display+an+infinity+symbol+using+html).

Comment: Now this is the first page that comes up when you google the question.

Answer (score 6):

According to [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20100808141115/http://comers.citadel.edu/math_sym2005.htm), it's `&infin;`.

Comment: HTML `<font>` is deprecated since 1998 in favour of CSS.

Answer (score 6):

∞ `&#8734;`

Answer (score 4):

Like ЯegDwight said, you can use the HTML entity `&infin`; or `&#8734;`. A easy source of getting these codes, is to look at [this entity list](http://brajeshwar.github.io/entities/).

You can also use them in CSS, which was what I was looking for, just like font-awesome does. A simple CSS based solution would be to have something like:

```
.infinity-ico:before {
    content: '\221E';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Infinity is a reserved character in HTML. Following are its values in various forms.

- Hex : 8734
- Decimal : 221E
- Entity : &infin;

To use in html code

```html
<p>The html symbol is &#8734; </p>
<p>The html symbol is &#x221E; </p>
<p>The html symbol is &infin; </p>
```

Reference : [HTML Symbols](https://www.tutorialkart.com/html-symbols/) - [HTML Infinity Symbol](https://www.tutorialkart.com/html-symbols/?hex=8734)