# How to include HTML entity symbols with tickFormat?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a [d3.v3.js](http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js) histogram and I'd like to fix the misleading extreme ticks of the bins because they are shown as a number but they actually are `-Inf` and `+Inf`.

I figured how to do this but I wanted to use the actual math symbol rather than `Inf`. The encoding is shown in the [SO question infinity-symbol-with-html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254913/infinity-symbol-with-html) i.e. using the HTML entity `&infin;` or `&#8734;` but when I do:

```
var ticks = 10;
var x = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain([min, max])
          .range([0, width]);
var xTicks = x.ticks(ticks);
var data = d3.layout.histogram().bins(xTicks)(values);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(ticks)
    .tickFormat(function (value) {
        var result: string;
        if (value === xTicks[0]) {
            result = '-&infin;'; // <======================== here -Inf
        } else
        if (value === xTicks[xTicks.length - 1]) {
            result = '+&infin;'; // <======================== here +Inf
        } else {
            result = tickFormat(value);
        }
        return result;
    });
```

the HTML entities are not recognized as such but taken as a string literal.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but closely related: [*"D3 append HTML not working in edge browser"*](/q/38064765). This should fix your problem.

Comment: @altocumulus thank you! However, I do not see how I can solve the this OP looking at that question/answer.

Comment: why can't you use direct **∞** value directly instead of &infin;

Comment: @Dinesh Cool good answer indeed it works!

Comment: You need to use the unicode escape sequence `\u221e` to get the infinity character.

Comment: I'm late to this party, but I'd like to drop my 2 cents: the issue here has nothing to do with D3, but with SVG instead: **HTML entities are not defined in SVG**, as @altocumulus explains in his linked answer.